# Error could not revert al hacer git revert

Tags: git

**1) Añado fichero.txt vacio a la carpeta de git:**

```
git add .
git commit --m "Commit Inicial"
```

**2) Edito fichero.txt:**

||||
A

||||

```
git add .
git commit --m "Commit A"
```

**3) Edito fichero.txt:**

||||
A
B

||||

```
git add .
git commit --m "Commit B"
```

**4) Edito fichero.txt:**

||||
A
B
C

||||

```
git add .
git commit --m "Commit C"
```

**5) Vuelvo al "Commit B":**

```
git revert "Commit B" (aquí realmente va el código que genera)
```

**Al hacer esto me responde lo siguiente:**

> error: could not revert cfa98f7... Subida Commit B hint: after
>   resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths hint: with 'git add
>   ' or 'git rm ' hint: and commit the result with 'git
>   commit'

Miro el contenido de fichero.txt y aparece lo siguiente:

```
A
<<<<<<< HEAD
B
C
=======
>>>>>>> parent of cfa98f7... Subida Commit B
```

Entiendo que me informa de un conflicto entre las líneas pero no comprendo nada.

¿No debería simplemente devolver el fichero al estado en que se encontraba en el Commit B?

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: prueba con git reset --hard, una pregunta solo quieres revertir un archivo o todo un commit?

Comment: Con git reset -hard perderia los commit posteriores al elegido en el reset y no es esa mi idea. Quiero revertir todo el commit, estoy realizando un pequeño tutorial para aprender a manejar git y me he encontrado con esta situación que no alcanzo a entender. Gracias ;-)

Comment: el conflicto que tienes es porque se modifico el mismo archivo, la solucion es que debes arreglarlo manualmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vale, realmente había entendido mal el concepto del comando revert.

Si quiero que el fichero vuelva al estado de "Commit B":

**NO tengo que hacer:**

```
git revert "commit B"
```

**sino:**

```
git revert "commit C"
```

Revert deshace los cambios de un commit por lo tanto los cambios a deshacer eran los del "Commit C" y asi el fichero queda como estaba con el "Commit B".

Es algo complejo de explicar con palabras quizás, espero que se entienda.

Gracias a todos.